how to use prop key in React Native
I need to display two arrays in two lines one below the other. however, they are now overlapping each other. The following message was also displayed:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

I tried to add a key to PreviewName so that the output would be correct, but I couldn’t figure out how to do it correctly. At the moment the error is as follows:
> [Error: TransformError SyntaxError: 
> C:\Users\Vera\nav_app1\app\(tabs)\two.tsx: 
> Unexpected token, expected "," (64:12)

  62 |
  63 |           <Text>
> 64 |             {value}
     |             ^
  65 |           </Text>
  66 |
  67 |       ))}]

Tell me how to fix this, I can’t figure it out
const DirectionLayout = () => {
  const [direction, setDirection] = useState('Объект');

  return (
  <SafeAreaView>
    <PreviewLayout

      selectedValue={direction}
      values={['Объект', 'Система']}
     
      setSelectedValue={setDirection}>
        
      <View style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: 'powderblue'}]} />
      <View style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: 'skyblue'}]} />
      <View style={[styles.box, {backgroundColor: 'steelblue'}]} />

    </PreviewLayout>

    <PreviewName
      values={['№', 'Содержание замечания', 'Статус' ]}>

    </PreviewName>
  </SafeAreaView>


  );
};

type PreviewLayoutProps = PropsWithChildren<{
 // label: string;
  values: string[];
  selectedValue: string;
  setSelectedValue: (value: string) => void;
}>;

type PreviewNameProps = PropsWithChildren<{
  values: string[];
}>;

const PreviewName = (
  {
    children,
    values,
  }:PreviewNameProps) => (
    
    <View style={styles.row}>
      {values.map(value => (
          
       
          <Text key={value} style={styles.title}>
            {value}
          </Text>

      ))}
    </View>
);

const PreviewLayout = ({
  children,
  values,
  selectedValue,
  setSelectedValue,
}: PreviewLayoutProps) => (
  <View style={{padding: 10, flex: 1}}>
    
    <View style={styles.row}>
      {values.map(value => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={value}
          onPress={() => setSelectedValue(value)}
          style={[styles.button, selectedValue === value && styles.selected]}>
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.buttonLabel,
              selectedValue === value && styles.selectedLabel,
            ]}>
            {value}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>
    <View style={styles.separator} lightColor="#eee" darkColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.1)" />
    <View style={[styles.container, ]}>{children}</View>
  </View>
);


export default DirectionLayout;


You seem to be doing the key prop correctly.  Your error is a syntax error related to something else.

Change your .map like so.
...

    <View style={styles.row}>
      {values.map((value, index) => ( // Make use of the index value
        <TouchableOpacity // Apply it here
          key={index}
          onPress={() => setSelectedValue(value)}
          style={[styles.button, selectedValue === value && styles.selected]}>
          <Text
            style={[
              styles.buttonLabel,
              selectedValue === value && styles.selectedLabel,
            ]}>
            {value}
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </View>

...

The value item might contain unique items but it might also contain the same value. Therefore index || i can be used. By doing this, each rendered item will have a unique key.
